# Vector to Raster Conversion in QGIS 3.4

Tags: rasterization

[image: Trying to Rasterize Vector Points to Raster]

I am trying to create a DEM from Vector points data extracted from Google Earth. What is the best method?

I get an error thrown each time, while trying to rasterize Vector point data to raster. Pictures attached

What is the guidance for right parameters to be put into the Processing fields of Rasterize (Vector to Raster)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the 'TIN interpolation' tool normally works well for creating a DEM from points. It's very simple to use, select your point file and the attribute containing elevation data, select your interpolation method (I normally use linear), and enter the extents and resolution you want your DEM to have.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me, thanks

Comment: @JagdishAswath - Don't forget to click the green-faded tick on the left-hand side of this answer to accept it :)